# How do binary search trees work in Java without pointers?

Tags: java, c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to compare the way a BST is implemented in Java and C++.  In Java a Node would look something like

```
class Node{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right; 
}
```

and in C++ it would be :

```
    class Node{
        int data;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;    
    }
```

I'm confused as the why the java approach is working.  I understand that in C++ left and right are pointers pointing to an area of memory that contains the next Node.  In Java I don't really get how everything ends up being connected.  Left and right are Nodes themselves, not pointers to nodes, so would each Node object in Java take up the space of 3 nodes (one for itself and 2 for its children)?  If anyone could explain what's really going on here in terms of how exactly all the Nodes are being connected and the difference in memory allocations it would be very helpful.

Also, can the same thing be done in C++? Could you just have Node left and Node right instead of pointers? If so, what's the advantage of using pointers in the first place? Thank you!

Comment: Java is using references. C++ also has references. Some languages don't have references.

Comment: Java uses pointers for nearly everything.  Every time you set a variable equal to an object, you're just storing a pointer to the object.  The difference is that Java doesn't let you directly access the pointer, manipulate or do math with it; it handles it automatically and sometimes seamlessly.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury no they are not and this doesn't make sense at all, if `left` and `right` were "`binary_search_tree` instances" as you said, there will be a run time error each time using this class (as the memory will not stop being allocated). Java's references are not instances. You can assign an instance to a reference, but it can also be `null` (`null` is not an instance of anything).

Comment: This is a bad questiont that shows very little understanding of the languages, you should read about Java's references. This is also very specific for no reason, this question is not about BST but about the type of variables in the languages. Other users seeking for this questiona and not understadning these concepts will never search for BST, they will not find this question. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @kbelder So the above the two ways I showed to code Node are equivalent, essentially just the syntax difference between java and c++?

Comment: @EricS Pretty much. Java handles everything safely under the covers while in C++ you need to do more work yourself, but it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Polikdir Sorry for the unnecessary specificity of the question, I am new here. Is there something you would like me to change the title to to correct this?  And as for the very little understanding, that's kinda why I'm asking about it, however people like you can make that very difficult to do

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But note that C++ references are quite unlike Java references, which are closer to C++ pointers (without the arithmetic.)

Comment: @NullUserException Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Java code the class type (`left` and `right`) member declarations *implicitly* declare pointers. There is no special notation for a pointer in Java, because most everything is handled via pointers. These are called **pointers** in the Java language specification, but they're known to most Java programmers as **references**.

In your example it's essentially just the syntax that differs between Java and C++, but do note that neither C++ pointers nor C++ references correspond directly to Java pointers.

Also note: You may encounter arguments that Java doesn't have pointers. For some reason that I can't grok (why are they unfamiliar with the specification of their favorite language, and why are they able to ignore e.g. getting `NullPointerException` on the screen?) some Java programmers will vehemently deny that the language has pointers. This is a mystery, but it can safely be ignored, I think.

Comment: You can't manipulate Java references the same way you can manipulate pointers in C or C++. And of course in C and C++ I can create a pointer to anything, but I can't get references to primitive types in Java.

Comment: I often wondered about this pointer-fobia. Maybe it is because C pointers do more than point to a single object.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the above two snippets of code do essentially the same thing.  What would be going on then if I wrote the Node class in C++ without pointers?  Would this be entirely different then the above 2?

Comment: @EricS: You can't write it in C++ without indirection, i.e. pointers or references. If you do then it's just invalid code specifying an infinite size class, and won't compile.

Comment: I think your comment "they are called pointers in the JLS" is misleading. To quote the JLS "the reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects". In other words, they are called reference values and described as pointers. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html

Comment: @sprinter: They are called both references and pointers, and described as pointers. E.g., "Abbreviations, as in buf holding a pointer to a buffer of some kind" (from §6.8.6 Local Variable and Parameter Names of the 1.0 spec) uses the term "pointer", not "reference". As stated in the answer, I don't grok the reasons why some Java programmers react so unreasonably to the terminology of their own language spec, so I have nothing more to offer than the bare facts; no guidance, sorry.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think the over-reaction is an attempt to distinguish from C-style pointers (e.g. explicit pointer arithmetic). But I agree it's a perfectly reasonable term for a thing that points to an object.